# Cartesian Join With Nonmatching Rows

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I can't get my query to work when a `LEFT` join doesn't match. I think this is related to the cartesian join. Here's a query that works:

```
select i.id, z.WeekNum, 0, count(s.id) from my156rowtable as i
left JOIN (select YEARWEEK( @startDate ) WeekNum, @startDate := date_add( @startDate, interval 1 week ) EndOfWeek
from 
(select @startDate := '2016-04-20') sqlv,
my156rowtable
limit 156 ) z
on 1=1
where i.id = 2 and s.id = 0
group by z.WeekNum, s.id
```

Which brings back:

```
|             2 |  201836 | 0 |        1 |
|             2 |  201837 | 0 |        1 |
|             2 |  201838 | 0 |        1 |
|             2 |  201839 | 0 |        1 |
|             2 |  201840 | 0 |        1 |
|             2 |  201841 | 0 |        1 |
```

but with my addition of `stats_to_my156rowtable` I get rows `201838` and `201839` missing.

```
select i.id, z.WeekNum, 0, count(s.id) from my156rowtable as i
left JOIN (select YEARWEEK( @startDate ) WeekNum, @startDate := date_add( @startDate, interval 1 week ) EndOfWeek
from 
(select @startDate := '2016-04-20') sqlv,
my156rowtable
limit 156 ) z
on 1=1
left join stats_to_my156rowtable as s
on i.id = s.sid and z.WeekNum = YearWeek(s.date)
where i.id = 2 and s.id = 0
group by z.WeekNum, s.id
```

returns:

```
|             2 |  201836 | 0 |                  8 |
|             2 |  201837 | 0 |                 14 |
|             2 |  201840 | 0 |                  9 |
```

if there is no match I'd like the `count` to be `0`. I figured I could this with a `case` or `coalesce` later but with no return I'm not finding much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition on the right table in the `WHERE` clause turn your `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.  Basically, it filter out rows that doesn't have id = 0, including your `NULL` rows.  Probably, moving the condition to the `ON` clause will solve your problem.

```
select i.id, z.WeekNum, 0, count(s.id) 
from my156rowtable as i
left JOIN (
    select YEARWEEK( @startDate ) WeekNum, @startDate := date_add( @startDate, interval 1 week ) EndOfWeek
    from (
        select @startDate := '2016-04-20'
    ) sqlv, my156rowtable
    limit 156 
) z on 1=1
left join stats_to_my156rowtable as s on i.id = s.sid and z.WeekNum = YearWeek(s.date) AND s.id = 0
where i.id = 2
group by z.WeekNum, s.id
```